# AWS passive failover pricing

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, failover

I have a reserved instance on AWS . I want to configure with route 53 failover policy. For this , I want to setup an ondemand passive server, which will takeover , once my primary reserved instance fail. I want to know the charges of this passive server. Will it charge me 24 hours, or only when primary server fails and it takes over.
My reserved instance is t2 large

Comment: This is completely off-topic for [SO] and I have voted to close it.

Comment: I just want to know, if passive server will always charge me or it will charge me only when traffic is moved toward it.

Comment: And this place isn't the right place to ask that question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A reserved instance is just like an other Amazon EC2 instance. The reservation is merely a pricing discount and a priority to get capacity when there is high demand.

The concept of a *passive server* is not used in AWS. If you mean a secondary server that can handle traffic if a primary server fails, then this is a common concept. In fact, rather than running a primary/second server configuration, it is recommended that you run as **High Availability** within AWS.

A *High Availability* architecture involves **running an application across multiple servers concurrently** so that, if one fails, the others can immediately take the load. In contrast to traditional Disaster Recovery scenarios where alternate servers are activated, under a High Availability architecture multiple servers in multiple data centers (Availability Zones) are *always* handling some of the traffic.

The easiest way to configure this is to use an Elastic Load Balancer across multiple AZs that distributes traffic to Amazon EC2 instances running in multiple AZs.

Instead, if you really only want one server running, you could have another server configured but in a `Stopped` state. There is no charge for a stopped EC2 instance (but disk storage is still charged). In case the main server fails, you could then `Start` the other server. Startup time would depend upon the operating system and the software you have configured on the server.

Comment: Thanks, but cost saving is my motto here. I have found another solution, I can add this reserved instance to ELB and can configure Auto Scaling group with minimum 1 server with launch configuration reserved instance AMI and put some health check policies there. I can also mark reserved instance as protected, so it can't be terminated. Health check policy will assure that once reserved instance is not working, then only pop up alternative server with my configured AMI

Comment: Yes, that will work. The "Reserved Instance" is a pricing benefit that will be applied again against a matching Amazon EC2 instance that is running. So, if one instance is replaced by another, the new one will receive the pricing benefit. A particular instance itself is not _Reserved_.